# Utilizing pytest to test API with required and optional fields

Tags: python, pytest

I have a series of tests that are used to test a REST API. The endpoints have required, optional and semi-optional (where a value is required only if one of the required fields has a specific value).

Right now I have a tests that look like this:

```
valid_types = ['shirt', 'pants', 'shoes']
valid_shipping = ['1', '2', '10']
valid_color = ['red', 'black', 'purple', 'mixed']
valid_patterns = ['glitter', 'spiral', 'stars', 'vertical']

@pytest.mark.parametrize("product_type", valid_types)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("shipping", valid_shipping)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("color", valid_color)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("patterns", valid_patterns)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("endpoint, success_code", [
    ('order', 200),
])
def test_valid_inputs(endpoint,
    success_code,
    product_type,
    shipping,
    color,
    patterns):
    # perform tests
```

In this example, the required fields are `product_type`, `shipping` and `color`. `patterns` is optional, unless `color` is `mixed`.

The problem with this test is that I can't make it generic to other end points. I have to have all of the required/optional logic in the test.

I have other tests that use the exact same parameters, but in some cases only `product_type` is required, or `shipping` is required or, etc. etc. That means I copy/paste the `parametrize` decorators repeatedly and have to have the required/optional checks in all of my tests instead of a more generic test.

Is there a way that I can specify if a parameter is required/optional(/semi-optional) using pytest so that I can utilize the same set of decorators and just add new endpoints to my last decorator? I'd like to make this much more generic so that I can quickly add new end points without needing to rebuild the required/optional logic in each test. It'll also knock down the code to a single generic test instead of 50 copies of almost identical, except for the required/optional, logic.

Comment: You can parameterize a fixture with all the parameters. Using that fixture in any test will parameterize that test too. This way, logic would be in one place.